# Parking lot diagram creator

Tags: drawing, diagram

[Parking lot diagrams](http://leadinganswers.typepad.com/leading_answers/2007/02/summarizing_pro.html) are used in SCRUM and FDD (Feature Driven Development).

I'm looking for software running on either Windows or Linux, that creates parking lot diagrams with good-looking output and minimal effort:
I'd input the feature set name, feature set status, the percentage completed, and a target date.

Comment: Perhaps you could link to a description of "parking lot diagrams" or specify more exactly the needed functionality.